# How to persist iOS app data across devices

Tags: ios

For example if I have a chip count in a game which is installed on iPhone 5. Now the user buys an iPhone 6 and does a restore to install all the apps including the game.

What are my options to migrate the chip count to the newly installed device?

Comment: iCloud? A database on your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build your own backend to store state like your count, or you could use iCloud drive.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more about the iCloud drive option?